# Help my ps3 is not working

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

My Ps3 comes on. I have tried 2 different HDMI cables. I have done the reset to restore video settings. Neither of these worked

I have even done a factory reset and still nothing. Sometimes it will say retrieving data but will then say no signal. At one time it said resolution not supported. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried another TV/Monitor?

Comment: Yes i have tried

Comment: I have tried 3 different TV  all HDMI 2 of the tv are smart TV.  I dont have rca jacks to try. I would have to either go buy some or borrow someones.im stumped

Comment: Update....i used a rf adaptor from a ps2....so i can watch movies but not will not load games at all

Comment: Update now i can play movies and ps2 games but not ps3 games im currently trying to find a blue ray disk movie so i can see if br lens is out

Comment: So not all ps2 games but all ps1 games.and still no ps3 games I've factory reset theps3 3 times and updated it and still clicking when i put a ps3 game in

Answer (score 0):

Since you've told it is "clicking" when you put a PS3 game, it's probably the BD drive. You can try to change it or to clean its lens.